# json_encode behaving differently on dev vs live servers

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, nginx

I am using laravel homestead (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, PHP 5.6.3-1, NGINX 1.6.2, MYSQL 5.6.19-0) as my dev machine and am pushing live to (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, PHP 5.6.6-1, Apache/2.4.12, MYSQL 5.5.41-0).

On my development environment, when I return json from my laravel api, numbers always seem to passed as numbers. On the live server numbers are returned as strings. I am trying to pinpoint if there is a setting or a version of one of the components that I need to change/upgrade.

What do I need to change to have my live server return numbers?

Comment: What PHP MySQL driver (php5-mysqlnd or php5-mysql) are you using for the live server? Use php5-mysqlnd.

Comment: Yep, php5-mysqlnd on local and php5-mysql on live. Just read through the doco and this looks like it could be the culprit. php5-mysqlnd seems to create better communication between mysql and php and can transfer data types better. Does this sound right?

Comment: Is anything numeric stumbling over the strings?

Comment: @kums you were right, it was the mysql driver. thank you very much for the help! Add it as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your live server is not using the php-mysqlnd driver, and your local server is using it, you are seeing the differences. Install php-mysqlnd on your live server to get it right.